# How to view MySQL formatted date and time when querying through Python?

Tags: python, mysql, database

So I have my Python file linked to the MySQL database, and I want to query for all the values in a couple tables, which includes a DATE entry, and a TIME entry. Now when I do this in MySQL, I get nicely formatted values like this: `2017-07-26, 12:30:00`

However, when I run the python file that queries the table, I instead get these values: `datetime.date(2017, 7, 26), datetime.timedelta(0, 45000))`

How do I fix this so running the Python file returns the Date and Time values in the same format I get when I query in MySQL?

Comment: Please paste your code in your question and not in images!

Comment: I updated my outputs to be in code format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime.date(2017, 7, 26)` is the Python object that represents the date, and `datetime.timedelta(0, 45000)` is a duration (here, 0 day and 45000 seconds) that we have to add to the date.

Python represents the combined date and time in `datetime.datetime` objects. We create one from the date and duration, then format it:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(2017, 7, 26)
delta = datetime.timedelta(0, 45000)

# We convert the date into a datetime object (same date, at midnight)
# and add the delta
date_and_time = datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time()) + delta

mysql_formatted_date = datetime.datetime.strftime(date_and_time, "%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S")

print(mysql_formatted_date)
#2017-07-26, 12:30:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) to convert a `datetime` object into any format you like.

e.g. for your case you can use -

```
value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S')
```